# Can't start Ignite (React Native boilerplate) project on ios simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

I just walked through ignite documentation and followed introtuction to start my new app with ignite.

```
$ npx ignite-cli@latest new PizzaApp
```

And then I try to run ios app on simulator with the command `npm run ios` and getting this error:

```
info React Native v0.72.1 is now available (your project is running on v0.71.7).
info Changelog: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.72.1
info Diff: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.71.7
info For more info, check out "https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading".
info Opening the app on iOS...
info Found Xcode workspace "PizzaApp.xcworkspace"
info Found booted iPhone 13
info Launching iPhone 13
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace PizzaApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme PizzaApp -destination id=2CA2813D-59DA-4449-8647-502B406E3CA9")
Command line invocation:
    /Users/admin/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace PizzaApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme PizzaApp -destination id=2CA2813D-59DA-4449-8647-502B406E3CA9

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (69 targets)
    Target 'PizzaApp' in project 'PizzaApp'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-PizzaApp' in project 'Pods' via file 'libPods-PizzaApp.a' in build phase 'Link Binary'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lCocoaAsyncSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-lDoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'EXApplication' in project 'Pods' via options '-lEXApplication' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'EXConstants' in project 'Pods' via options '-lEXConstants' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'EXFileSystem' in project 'Pods' via options '-lEXFileSystem' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'EXFont' in project 'Pods' via options '-lEXFont' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'EXSplashScreen' in project 'Pods' via options '-lEXSplashScreen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Expo' in project 'Pods' via options '-lExpo' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ExpoDevice' in project 'Pods' via options '-lExpoDevice' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ExpoKeepAwake' in project 'Pods' via options '-lExpoKeepAwake' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ExpoLocalization' in project 'Pods' via options '-lExpoLocalization' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ExpoModulesCore' in project 'Pods' via options '-lExpoModulesCore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Boost-iOSX' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Boost-iOSX' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Fmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-PeerTalk' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-RSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-RSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FlipperKit' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipperKit' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCT-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNBootSplash' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNBootSplash' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCAsyncStorage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCAsyncStorage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNGestureHandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNReanimated' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Codegen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Core' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAppDelegate' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-cxxreact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-hermes' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-hermes' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsi' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsi' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsiexecutor' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsiexecutor' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsinspector' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsinspector' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-logger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-logger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-perflogger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-perflogger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReactCommon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'SocketRocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lSocketRocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Yoga' in project 'Pods' via options '-lYoga' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'YogaKit' in project 'Pods' via options '-lYogaKit' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-lfmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'glog' in project 'Pods' via options '-lglog' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'libevent' in project 'Pods' via options '-llibevent' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'react-native-safe-area-context' in project 'Pods' via options '-lreact-native-safe-area-context' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
    Target 'Pods-PizzaApp' in project 'Pods'
        ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods'
        ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods'
        ➜ Explic
```

FYI, my xcode version is `15 beta 3` and node version is `18.16.1` (lts).

I am expecting it to be running on ios simulator. Can you help me?

Here is full console output I am seeing on my cmd: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fdJg_bvyZ26erkFRvxfEKssZJe84uQTTxA82iPuOs0Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you install the pods?

Comment: Sure. I installed pods successfully in `ios`. Pod version is `1.12.1` fyi.

Comment: I didn't see any error on your console output

Comment: Sec I will post the rest of the console output.

Comment: Here is full console output I am seeing on my cmd: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fdJg_bvyZ26erkFRvxfEKssZJe84uQTTxA82iPuOs0Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Checkout this: https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1670, some people already dealing with very same issue, maybe helps